# Realizar calculos en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Buenas soy nuevo en rails tengo la siguiente duda.

Si tengo un modelo de producto con costo y precio ¿Cómo haría para calcular el precio dependiendo del costo?

El precio seria, costo * 30%

¿Se realiza en el modelo o el constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías crear un metodo dentro de tu clase Producto en el que realizarás la operación, y así utilizar el método en lugar de la operación directa.

Algo como lo siguiente deberá funcionar.

```
class Producto  
  def precio(sobrecosto)
    self.costo * (1.00 + sobrecosto)
  end
end
```

De esta manera, podrías obtener directamente el precio en cada producto. Un beneficio de este camino, es que podrías tener un `sobrecosto` distinto por producto, o incluso con un poco de más código, implementar un sobrecosto global para todos tus productos, por ejemplo del `30%` y eventualmente cambiarlo modificando ese número en un sólo lugar, en lugar de muchos otros.

Como comentas que queres nuevo en rails, voy a detallar un poco mi respuesta.

En la segunda línea estamos creando un método de instancia llamado `precio` que acepta un argumento, en este caso es `sobrecosto`.

En la línea tres, `self` se refiere al objeto en el que estás aplicando el método, luego `costo` es el costo que tienes en tu base de datos para ese producto, `sobrecosto` es el valor que quieras darle, por ejemplo 30% ó 0.30.

Ejemplo de implementación:

```
manzana = Producto.create(costo: 100)
puts manzana
=> #<Producto:0x007ff2f823c858>

puts manzana.costo
=> 100

manzana.precio(0.30)
=> 130
```

Espero que te sirva. Por favor, avísame si tienes dudas de este código.

Answer (score 0):

Para sumar el 30% del costo:

```
total = costo + (costo * 0.3)
```

o

```
costo += costo * 0.3;
```